# What happens when I compare two string in MIPS (assembly)

Tags: string, assembly, compare, mips

So I want to ask what will happen, if I do code like this:

```
.data
    $$tmp0: .asciiz "pies"
    $$tmp1: .asciiz "kot"
    a: .word 0:1

.text
    main:
    la $t1, $$tmp0
    la $t0, $$tmp1
    bne $t0, $t1, ELSE_END_IF_LABEL0
    li $t0, 2
    sw $t0, a
    j END_IF_LABEL0
    ELSE_END_IF_LABEL0:
    END_IF_LABEL0:
```

This code will compare some adresses or what does it do?

Comment: You're just comparing addresses, and these will be different, so you'll branch to `ELSE_END_IF_LABEL0`.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if I compare addresses or what.

Comment: Now would be a good idea to learn to use a debugger so that you can step through the code and see what's actually going on.